# Help with answering a question

Tags: microeconomics

[image]

Hi, could someone help with this question? I understand that they'll consume different amounts of tea at the market equilibrium, but I'm confused about how to determine their marginal benefits. Is it the same since the market-clearing price is what their marginal benefit is equal to?